# Upgrade an unsupported release of Ubuntu(Ubuntu 10.04)!

Tags: upgrade, updates, 10.04, update-manager

I want to upgrade my computer from **Ubuntu 10.04**. But when I go to open the Update Manager, it says that my version is old (as if I didn't already know that) and that I need to update, but the manager won't run. I honestly have no idea what to do from this point, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If system is that old, you may not support the new (to you) Unity as you have the old gnome2 panels. My 2006 laptop could just barely run Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity but with the gnome-panel or fallback it worked well. You may want Lubuntu or Xubuntu. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors fallback/gnome-panel https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeFlashback?action=show&redirect=GnomeFlashback

Answer (score 0):

You could start by upgrading to 12.04, and then 14.04 and so forth!
All the old images are still here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/

You want to make the jump from LTS to LTS for fast upgrade to the present LTS 16.04.

Best of luck!